# Is the Dutch PMs call to »restez chez soi« grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaire

The Dutch Prime Minister Mark Rutte [wrote on Twitter](https://twitter.com/MinPres/status/1339495655501393920) in French, German, and Dutch:

> restez chez soi, bleib zuhause, blijf thuis

Is the French phrase *restez chez soi* grammatically correct?  Here *restez* would be the second person plural imperative, but then shouldn't the pronoun be *vous* rather than *soi* (*restez chez vous*), which would appear to be the infinitive (*rester chez soi*)?  Why is it (not) correct?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your analysis is fine. It is grammatically incorrect. It should be "Rester chez soi" (infinitive), or "Restez chez vous".

Comment: You might want to add that all other pronouns would also have been correct (but with different meanings): *Restez **chez moi**, restez **chez toi**, restez **chez elle**, restez **chez lui**, restez **chez nous**, restez **chez vous**, restez **chez elles**, restes **chez eux***.

Comment: @jlliagre What would _restez chez toi_ would mean?  "You [formal] stay with you [informal]"?  Is there a context in which this would make sense?

Comment: @gerrit No, that would be: *You (plural) stay at your (singular, informal) home*. (*You all, stay at thy home*).

Comment: e.g.: *Toi avec tes virus, restez chez toi !*

Comment: An important point is that "rester chez soi" and "restez* chez soi" are pronounced the same in French, making this spelling error understandable.

Comment: Is the grammar at all changed by the sentence being an order?

Comment: @Mast : I am not sure to understand your question, but "rester chez soi" being infinitive, can't be an order. So "restez chez vous!" would apply, in order to be an order.

Comment: @Ouch42 it was meant as an order, so that's the first problem then. Thanks.

Comment: @Mast I touched upon this in another answer.

Comment: @jlliagre: I would assume the third person would be wrong here as the message is to _not_ visit others.

Comment: @Flater Indeed, the reason why I wrote "but with different meanings". I was talking about grammatical correctness, not about accuracy.

Comment: (*analyse* → *[analysis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/analysis#Noun)* (analyse [is a verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/analyse#Verb)))

Answer (score 6):

It's technically grammatically incorrect but I think that's failing to see the forest for the trees. This tweet is part of a cross-border campaign and, as the whole context shows, the French phrase is apparently lifted from the video and the subtitles in the Belgian prime minister's contribution rather than something the Dutch prime minister wrote out of the blue.

In this context, the most striking thing linguistically is that “*rester chez soi*” is not a good translation for “*blijf thuis*” or “*bleib zuhause*”. If it was, the “z” would only be a small typo or transcription error. As others have pointed out, “*rester*” and “*restez*” sound exactly the same in French so the spelling mistake doesn't make the whole sentence feel agrammatical.

In fact, the closest French translation would be “*reste à la maison*”. A less literal but possibly more idiomatic translation would be “*ne sortez pas*”. Incidentally, both of these refer to one's home (as opposed to the whole/country region as “*thuis*” or “*zuhause*” might in Dutch or German).

If you consider that officials typically use a more formal register in France than in the Netherlands (not necessarily true when comparing Belgium and Germany), it could be “*restez chez vous*” (German: “*bleiben Sie zuhause*”, which is what Laschet — but not De Croo or Rutte — says in the video). That's also the plural form in French (German: “*bleibt zuhause*”). This discrepancy in tone and meaning is the main reason why that phrase feels improper and presumably hasn't been produced by a native French speaker.

Comment: I did notice the German form was inappropriate as well (it's not grammatically wrong, but it addresses a single person informally).

Comment: @gerrit why shouldn't a Prime Minister address people informally?

Comment: @user253751 One can discuss formal or informal (in Germany and I believe France too politicians would always address voters with the formal form), but in this context using the singular form is simply not right.

Comment: Re: "‘*rester chez soi*’ is not a good translation for ‘*blijf thuis*’ or ‘*bleib zuhause*’": Could you explain why this is? Is *rester chez soi* inherently awkward in some way, or is it just that the German and Dutch differ from it in some way, or something else? (Sorry if this is a stupid question -- I don't know German or Dutch, so I may be missing something obvious.)

Comment: @ruakh "Rester chez soi" just means something quite different, closer to English "staying home", German "zuhause bleiben", Dutch "thuis blijven".

Comment: @Relaxed: Thanks for your reply, but what do *blijf thuis* and *bleib zuhause* mean? How are they different from *rester chez soi*? (Could you adjust your answer so that it doesn't assume knowledge of German and Dutch?)

Comment: @ruakh I have the feeling I already explained that in the answer and do not assume knowledge of German or Dutch, will see if I can clarify further. What's your native language / the one you want to use as a reference? Is the difference between *rester chez soi* et *reste chez toi* clear to you? Bleib zuhause = reste chez toi = stay home / zuhause bleiben = rester chez soi = staying home.

Comment: @Relaxed: My primary language is English. I also speak French fairly well. And I think I now understand your objection, thank you: I think you're saying that an infinitive like « rester chez soi » can't be used as an order? But I don't think that's true in general; for example, signs like « ne pas fumer » ("no smoking") and « ne pas stationner » ("no parking") are commonplace. It's a kind of officialese used when addressing the public.

Comment: @ruakh I am basing this on my intuition as a native French speaker who is also fluent in German and has some knowledge of Dutch. I am not trying to infer a rule from it or claim it's true in general but I am positive that “rester chez soi” is not an order and not a good translation for the Dutch/German sentences, even if you're right that an infinitive can be as in “attendre ici”. It's not uncommon in cookbooks either but I feel it would be odd to use “rester chez soi” in that way or as a complete sentence (something like “rester chez soi est recommandé” would be more acceptable).

Comment: @Relaxed Dans une liste de choses à faire/ne pas faire ce serait possible d'avoir l'infinitif; ça reviendrait à la même chose que ton « ...est recommandé ».

Comment: @20goto10 Oui j'ai songé à ça après avoir mentionné les livres de cuisine, ce serait possible. Ça reste un exemple un peu artificiel et assez éloigné du contexte d'origine. Ça fonctionne d'ailleurs de la même manière en allemand, on écrit généralement une recette de cuisine à l'infinitif mais là les phrases d'origine sont bien à l'impératif.

Comment: Oui, je réagissais seulement aux commentaires, indépendamment du contexte de la question.

Answer (score -3):

rester chez soi is grammatically correct in my opinion. As an example you would say « stay at your own place is better than staying at your mother’s place ». Rester chez soi est mieux que chez sa mère
But hey, this is one man opinion

Comment: You missed the *Z*...

Comment: Yes, "rester chez soi" is grammatically correct. No one said it wasn't here. Or did we?

Comment: No. I view the video and in my opinion the prime minister used it properly

Comment: What video? The question is about a twitter post.

Comment: The question is about a twitter post, yes, and on a video, how could you possibly know if the PM said "restez chez soi" or "rester chez soi"? It sounds exactly the same, at least where I am from.

Comment: No problem guys ;-)

Comment: *[Well, you know, that's just like, your opinion, man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0aDEvmf5u0&t=2m43s)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Hope the Dude will get better.